# Why does Object.create( proto ) appear to be ignoring the prototype argument in this example?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In this very simple example:

```
let myProtoObj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
};

let myObj = Object.create(myProtoObj);
console.log(myObj);
```

I expect to see `{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }` logged to the console. Instead, I get `{}`. Looking through the documentation on MDN doesn't make it clear to me what I'm doing wrong, but I assume it has something to do with how I've declared `myProtoObj` or invoked `Object.create()`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your console probably only logs own properties. There is no specification for what you should see there. Try `myObj.foo` and you should get `1`. You can also try `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj) === myProtoObj)`

Comment: This appears to be correct, though not a default behavior I was expecting to get out of my console. This would be my accepted answer.